# Musical isomorphisms and 1-forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, exterior-algebra

In [this lecture](https://youtu.be/9fu4QHskfl0?t=27m43s) by James Cook [musical morphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) are introduced:

The exterior differential of a function (function corresponding to a 0-form) results in a 1-form (otherwise referred to as a *work* form).

The gradient at every point of a manifold would form a field

$$\vec F =\sum F^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg\vert_p$$

which would yield the work form $\omega$ at a given point through the operation

$$\omega_{\vec F}=\flat \vec F$$

resulting in

$$\omega = \omega_1 dx + \omega_2 dy + \omega_3 dz.$$

[I modified the notation from the original recording from $\alpha$ to $\omega$, although this may wrong.]

> Is the flat $\flat$ simply making reference to the covectors, $dx_i$ or $\mathrm e^i$ elements in the cotangent bundle?

Comment: Beware, I am not always careful enough about writing $x^i$ for coordinate functions. In some contexts, we would want $dx^i$ for the co-vector field defined by the exterior derivative of the coordinate function $x^i: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $U$ is some coordinate domain. Most often in my classes, $U$ would just be a subset of real $n$-space, but, I should check your link... yes, that is all a discussion of forms on $\mathbb{R}^3$, I don't do much with bundles in that course, it's all on the base space as far as I recall.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook My apologies in advance for transcription mistakes. Your lectures are very interesting and it's great you make them public.

Comment: Thanks :) no apologies needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $\flat$ is used to denote the isomorphism between vectors and covectors provided by a metric on a given vector space $g: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in particular,
$$ \flat v = g(v, \cdot) \qquad \text{which means} \qquad \flat v = \alpha \ \ \& \ \ \ \ \alpha (x) = g(v,x) $$
for each $x \in V$. This construction naturally extends to a manifold with a metric tensor field since the metric tensor provides a metric for the tangent space at a given point in the manifold. Notice, this could be a Riemannian manifold if the metric is positive definite, but generally we only insist the metric be nondegenerate and symmetric. Sylvester's Law of Inertia tells us that there exists a coordinate system in which the metric has a formula of the form:
$$ g(x,y) = x^1y^1+ \cdots + x^ry^r-x^{r+1}y^{r+1}- \cdots -x^ny^n = \sum x^iy_i (\text{using notation below defined})$$
for example, Minkowksi metric is often given with $r=3$ and $n=4$ or sometimes we see the pattern $-+++$. Sometimes we extend the meaning of $\flat$ to the components of $v = \sum v^i \partial_i$ in the sense $\flat v^i = v_i$ where:
$$ v_i = \sum_j g_{ij}v^j $$
in other words, the $\flat$ is used to lower the indices from contravariant to covariant. This is the origin of the joke of using $\flat$ for this map and conversely $\sharp$ for $\sharp v_i = v^i$ where the inverse metric (as a matrix) $g^{ij}$ is used; $\sharp v_i = v^i =\sum_j g^{ij} v_j$. There are many things about this written in **Gravitation** by Misner Thorn and Wheeler, I think this is also nicely discussed in John Lee's **Introduction to Smooth Manifolds**, page 341-343.